# Model property always get false value from a checkbox even if its check. data is json from ajax call

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

I have a form that when submitted will call the code below:

```
$.ajax({
        url: '/Company/CheckError',
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify($(this).serializeObject()),
        dataType: 'json',
        processData: false,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (data) {
    }
});
```

if my IsActive checkbox is unchecked I found out that it returns the following json data:

```
{"Email":"test@test.com","Name":"test","Phone":"","IsActive":"false","submitType":"","Id":"59"}
```

which I found natural. But if checked the IsActive checkbox, it will return this json data:

```
{"Email":"test@test.com","Name":"test","Phone":"","IsActive":["true","false"],"submitType":"","Id":"59"}
```

Now in my controller,

```
public ActionResult Method(SomeModel model)
{

}
```

the other property binds just fine. But the model.IsActive is always false. I thought MVC handles this correctly by binding the true value and not the value from the hidden input for checkbox.

Am I missing something? Advance thanks for your help =')

Comment: `"false"` is a string value, try using `false`  - I came across this because when I set `true` the json came back with the value `false` *grumble*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like this:

Model:

```
public class SomeModel 
{
    public bool IsActive  { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new SomeModel();
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(SomeModel model)
    {
        return Json(new { success = model.IsActive });
    }
}
```

View:

```
@model SomeModel

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div>
       @Html.LabelFor(x => x.IsActive)
       @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.IsActive)
    </div>
    <p><input type="submit" value="OK"></p>
}

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('form').submit(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: this.action,
            type: this.method,
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data.success);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the following into your controller method:

```
model.IsActive = model.IsActive.Contains("true");
```